# Наследование шаблона с++

Tags: c++, наследование, шаблоны-с++

Ожидалось в `Child` иметь доступ к `val`, но компилятор запротестовал(почему?):

```
template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    T val;
};

template<typename T>
struct Child : Base<T>
{
    void show() {cout << val + val2 << endl;};
    T val2;
};

int main ()
{
    Child<int> obj;
    obj.val = 123;
    obj.val2 = 456;
    obj.show();
}
```

-

```
error: ‘val’ was not declared in this scope
  void show() {cout << val + val2 << endl;};
```

Comment: Сам класс не имеет такое поле, и нужно указать  член какого класса является val

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Следует указать префикс с базовым типом:

```
void show() {cout << Base<T>::val + val2 << endl;};
```

иначе компилятор не может определить к чему относится идентификатор `val`

Comment: А с чем может быть связано такое дополнительное требование? Ведь в обычных классах этого делать не нужно

Comment: @Vitaly Потому что при разборе кода шаблона (еще до инстанцирования) у компилятора отсутствует информация о наличии в базовом классе тех или иных полей.